# Additional spaces inside list element

Tags: support, markdown, list

This is proper rendering?

Sample list

- `[small]`
- `[b i g]`

  - foo

for this code:

```
 * `[small]`
 * `[b i g]`

    * foo
```

the `[b i g]` should have smaller size. Is this bug or feature?

Comment: `[b i g]` is inside a `<p>`, which adds padding, while `[small]` isn't. Odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to consider this in terms of element hierarchy. Inside your second list item, your full content is as follows:

```
`[b i g]`

* foo
```

That *entire* block of text has to be rendered through Markdown before it can be placed back inside the parent list item as completed HTML. In markdown, a line-break below a line of text will start a new paragraph. So the first line gets converted to a paragraph and then you start a new list after that, resulting in the final rendering you see.

The only way to get around that is to make Markdown think that there is only *one* paragraph to be rendered, which means you can't have an extra line-break in between your content anywhere within that single list-item.

So something like this would work:

```
* `[small]`
* `[b i g]`
    * foo
```

Rendered version:

> - `[small]`
> - `[b i g]`
>
>   - foo

Note that adding another paragraph *after* the list will result in an oddity where there is no space between the list item and the next line of text, because by default a list inside a list does not have any padding on the bottom.

So this:

```
* `[small]`
* `[b i g]`

    * foo

  Hello
```

Would end up looking like this:

> - `[small]`
> - `[b i g]`
>
>   - foo
>
>   Hello